# How can I find answers I've downvoted?

Tags: feature-request, support, answers, down-votes, recent-activity

I'm aware I can view **all** of my downvotes by going [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563422/danny-beckett?tab=votes&sort=downvote):

> [image]

But there are *reams* of downvotes matched.

I also tried looking at the advanced search operators, but there's nothing useful there.

How can I view **only the *answers*** I've downvoted?

Comment: You can find them through your `/reputation` page, but that's hardly handy.

Comment: @Mat Nice, I hadn't thought of using that! Have a look at my answer...

Comment: Maybe a feature request. Similar to `hasaccepted` in the search results. It could be `medownvote:` `answer`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quick & *dirty* option: navigate to your [/reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation), open your browser's dev tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome), and dump this to the JavaScript console:

```js
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];
var links = '<h1>Answers I\'ve downvoted:</h1>';
var re = /^ \d +(\d+) +\(-1/gm;
var ma;
while (ma = re.exec(pre.innerHTML)) {
  links += '<a href="/a/'+ma[1]+'">'+ma[1]+'</a><br>';
}
document.body.innerHTML = links;
```

Comment: Dirty maybe, but _quick_, and in-browser too. Nice.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to get a list of answers as URLs:

1. Go to [stackoverflow.com/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy)
4. Fire up [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (or your favourite Linux alternative)
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste)
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (find & replace)
7. Search Mode: Regular expression

> **Find:** `^(?!.*\(-1\)$).*$\r\n`
>
> **Replace:** `<blank>`

> **Find:** `^ *\d+ +(\d+).*$`
>
> **Replace:** `https://stackoverflow.com/a/$1/`

Leaves something like:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12419xxx/
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12549xxx/
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12556xxx/

Comment: You can drop the `www.` part, it's not necessary. Saves a few bytes :)

Comment: Yeah, like SE is worried about a few bytes...